# In Python project, how are installed libraries packaged when creating distribution?

Tags: python-3.x, libraries, setuptools, python-wheel, python-packaging

I am trying to learn about packaging of Python projects. This [page](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) has information about how to create distributable files.

My question is how does the installed third-party python library get packaged along with this ? Is there any file that mentions all the libraries to be installed for this project?

I searched many answers but none gave satisfactory solution. Thanks!

Comment: You should specify the referenced third party packages in the file `setup.py`. This means that the package manager can check and obtain the version during the installation. You can get more information [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) and [here](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html).

Comment: If you use `pip freeze` in the command line, you can easily copy and modify the output and add line by line to `install_requires = [] `.

Answer (score -2):

From the page you linked in the setup.py there is an option called packages. It reads:

`packages=setuptools.find_packages(),`

Below it explains what it does:

packages is a list of all Python import packages that should be included in the distribution package. Instead of listing each package manually, we can use find_packages() to automatically discover all packages and subpackages. In this case, the list of packages will be example_pkg as that’s the only package present.

So this is where you list all your imports. However if you do `setuptools.find_packages()` it looks like it will automatically find the imports to package with it.

More on it here:
https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. `find_packages()` finds importable directories from **the current project**. The OP asks how to list **3rd-party libraries**. You're confused because the word "packages" is heavily overloaded.

Comment: 3rd-party or not, it will still be imported and thus be found no?

Comment: 3rd-party libraries will **not** be found with `find_packages()`.

Comment: @phd find_packages() does not detect 3rd party libraries & transitive dependency? But the documentation seems to be suggesting otherwise. Can you explain?

Comment: as phd wrote, `find_packages` is used to find packages in *the code that you are writing*. For example, [in the official python packaging example project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject), they write `find_packages(where='src')` to find all the packages that they themselves defined. They could have just as well written `["sample"]` instead, the name of their package.